# What do I do if my Schengen visa is rejected because of financial needs and im a student?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, finland

My Schengen visa to Finland got rejected because of insufficient means of subsistence but i am a student in the university and have no sources of funds, being aware of this my host vividly stated that they take care of my financial needs. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your relationship to your "host" and why are they paying for your tuition and living expenses?

Comment: I don’t mean to sound harsh but if you ‘have no source of funds’ how were you intending to survive if your application had been approved? The financial means requirement is quite clear https://migri.fi/en/income-requirement-for-students

Comment: @Traveller The OP did mention a host and the page you found is not relevant for Schengen visas.

Comment: @Relaxed I understood the OP’s question to be about a student visa for Finland. If it’s about a Schengen visa to *visit* Finland, then the OP should make that clear.

Comment: @Traveller Schengen visas are for short stays that's why I read the question differently. Additional clarity cannot hurt but I still see no reason to assume otherwise by default.

Answer (score 3):

We don't know much about your situation but based on what little information you provided, you may not have any effective recourse. An appeal, even when you have a solid claim, is long and complicated. And you do not appear to have any grounds for appeal. Legally, you're not entitled to a short-stay visa and the consulate is under no obligation to provide anything else than this boilerplate justification.

A lack of financial means as a young adult is bound to look like a red flag to the consulate, even if you have a host or sponsor to cover your expenses. In that context, being a student can actually play against you: it means you have less binding you to your current place of residence and fewer reasons to go back there. The system is not designed to give everybody an opportunity to get a visa.

Comment: If the application did not mention the host, did not establish that the host is financially capable of supporting the visit, or did not establish the relationship between the applicant and the host, then it is possible that a subsequent application that does do these things would be successful.  In that case, a new application, rather than an appeal, would be indicated.